# How do you keep the popup open after form submission when using angular material md-dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this piece of code that works fine. I want to keep the model open so that I can keep adding values.

As it stands now every time I click okay, the form submits and closes the model. I would love for it to submit and keep the model open.

```html
<md-dialog aria-label="New Mark" flex="30">
    <form ng-cloak>
        <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <h2>New Mark</h2>
                <span flex></span>
                <md-button aria-label="close" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="hide()">
                    <ng-md-icon icon="cancel"></ng-md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>

        <div class="md-dialog-content">
            <form name="studentForm" ng-submit="dialog.ok()">
                <div layout="column" layout-sm="column" >
                    <div class="ms-TextField">
                        

                    <div class="ms-TextField">
                        <label class="ms-Label">Mark</label>
                        <input required min="1" max="{{::passedData.totalmark}}" valid-number  ng-model="student.mark" limit-to-max required class="ms-TextField-field">
                        <span class="ms-TextField-description">
                            <span ng-if="errors.title">{{::errors.title[0]}}</span>
                            </span>
                    </div>


                </div>


                <button aria-label="submit"  ng-click="answer(student)"
                        class="g-button blue">0K
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: post your controller code here to let others know what you have done with the ok button. BTW, if there isn't executable code snippet right now, just use the normal code block or else you have to make the code snippet works well.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure
but you have two tag form 
 and 
and on submit (or click) two function are called, dialog.ok() and answer(student)

are you sure dialog.ok() don't hide the modal?

Comment: I saw that, even after removing dialog.ok(), still no change

Comment: if you remove the first form tag <form ng-cloak>? if don't work, we will need your controller